# missing metriks spring kafka listener

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, spring-kafka

I use KafkaListener to get a message from kafka, but I don't get the spring_kafka_listener metrics

registering a metric with the name spring_kaf_ka_listener did not give results, an error message will appear that such a metric has already been registered

the addition did not give any result
cf.addListener(new MicrometerConsumerListener<>(new SimpleMeterRegistry()));

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getGroupId());
        return props;
    }


    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        final StringDeserializer jsonDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();
        ConsumerFactory<String,String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
            new StringDeserializer(), jsonDeserializer
        );
        //I tried to add it but it didn't give any result
        cf.addListener(new MicrometerConsumerListener<>(new SimpleMeterRegistry()));//
        return cf;

    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(false);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper headerMapper() {
        return new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer listener enables the native Kafka metrics, the `spring_kafka_listener` metrics are controlled by the `micrometerEnabled` container property, which is true by default.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer

The metrics will only be captured if Micrometer is on the class path.

If you can't figure it out, provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is wrong.